# Given the density function: $\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right), \space x > 0$ find $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{81}X_i > 170\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that $X_1,X_2...X_{81}$ are independent random variable with the same probability density function
$$\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right), \space x > 0$$

Find   $$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{81}X_i > 170\right)$$

My problem is figuring out the expected value and variance. Is it just the coefficient of what's inside the exp brackets? Not too sure about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $E(X_1+\cdots +X_n)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_n)$, and, by independence, $\text{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\text{Var}(X_1)+\cdots +\text{Var}(X_n)$.

The $X_i$ have exponential distribution parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$. It is a standard fact that the mean of such an exponentially distributed random variable is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and the variance is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$.

**Remark:** If proof for the "standard facts" is needed, for the mean calculate $\int_0^\infty \lambda xe^{-\lambda x}\,dx$, using integration by parts. For the variance of such a random variable $X$, use the fact that the variance is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$, and find $E(X^2)$ by integration by parts.

Comment: why is it then that if the probability density function was $exp(-x)$ then variance and mean is $1$?

Comment: If it is $\exp(-x)$ then $\lambda=1$, so $\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=1$. But in our case $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ so the mean is $2$ and the variance is $4$.

Comment: so $\lambda$ is equal to the coefficient before the exp always?

Comment: Well, there are two standard ways to parametrize the exponential, as $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, in which case the mean is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, or as $\frac{1}{a}e^{-x/a}$, in which case $a$ is the mean.